# Software recommendation: PDF reader with frictionless highlighting

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

I have tried many PDF readers (evince, okular, FoxitReader, etc.) and found evince the most minimal and practical one. Yet, with version 6 of Zotero, came a built-in PDF viewer with some features. Of them, one greatly changed my experience in reading pdfs, and that's the ease of color-coded highlighting: *With no extra click, a little pop-up with a few colors will show up once you select a piece of text in Zotero's PDF viewer. If you further select one of the colors, the text will be highlighted with the corresponding color* (very similar to the experiences you may have with the [Textmarker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/textmarkerpro/) plugin on the web).

I like to have that feature off Zotero as well. **Do you know any viewer that has such a feature or can be configured for that?** Those that I've tried, indeed, all let you highlight with several colors, but after tons of extra clicks.

Thanks!

---

**Note**: You may be wondering why I don't import my PDFs to Zotero and read everything there. This I don't do because I don't what my files to clutter with the library that I keep in Zotero.